# Is it valid to include images with <object> instead of <img>?

Tags: image, html, object-tag

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10375755/201952), where the poster casually states as fact that `<object>` should be used instead of `<img>` to embed images in HTML documents.

> I'm developing a web app at the moment, and, being a perfectionist, I try to make it all shiny and compliant with all the standards. As far as I know, the `<img>` tag is to be deprecated in the upcoming standards for xHTML, and as nowadays even IE is able to handle `<object>` properly, I wanted to use the `<object>` tag for all the images on my site

It became clear that the "upcoming standards" the poster was talking about was the abandoned [XHTML2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/) spec, which didn't even formally deprecate `<img>` anyway.  (Although there were apparently [rumors](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-77173.html) to that effect.)

To the best of my knowledge, I've not seen anyone in the web development community advocating for the usage of the general-purpose `<object>` tag over the arguably more semantic and definitely more compatible `<img>` tag.

Is there a good reason to use `<object>` instead of `<img>`?  Should `<object>` even be used at all in place of `<img>` – what might this break?

Answer (score 19):

To answer the question in the heading: yes, it is *valid*, of course. The validity of an `object` element does not even depend on the type of data being embedded. If you meant to ask whether it is *correct*, then the answer is yes, there is nothing in the specifications that would forbid it or recommend against it.

Among the possible reasons for using `object` to embed an image, the most practical is that it allows the fallback content to contain HTML markup, such as headings, lists, tables, and phrase markup. The `img` element lets you specify only plain text as fallback content—even paragraph breaks cannot be specified.

For accessibility reasons, any image should have fallback content to be rendered e.g. when the document is used in nonvisual browsing (screen reader, Braille, etc.) or the image is not displayed for one reason or other. For any content-rich image (say, an organization chart, or a drawing describing a complex process), the fallback content needs to be long and needs to have some structure.

However, it is rare to use `object` for embedding an image. The importance of fallback content is not widely understood, and practical economical and technical considerations often cause fallback issues to be ignored. Moreover, `object` has a long history of slow, buggy, and qualitatively poor implementation in browsers. Only recently has it become viable to use `object` fairly safely for image inclusion.

The question which element is more semantic is mostly futile, and answers typically reflect just various ways to misunderstand the concept “semantic.” Both `img` and `object` mean inclusion (embedding) of external content. The `img` element is in principle for the inclusion of images, whatever that means, though it has also been used to include videos. For the `object` element, the `type` attribute can be used to specify the type of embedded content, down to specific image type, e.g. `type=image/gif`, or it may be left open.

This implies that the `object` element is more flexible: you can leave the type unspecified, letting it to be specified in HTTP headers. This way, the type of the embedded data could be changed without changing the `object` element or the embedding document in general; e.g., you could start with a simple version where the embedded content is an image, later replaced it by an HTML document (containing an image and text for example).

Answer (score 10):

The only time I've ever seen an object used to show an image is to create a "fallback" when the intended object couldn't be loaded for whatever reason. Take this [example from the W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.3.1):

```
<OBJECT title="The Earth as seen from space" classid="http://www.observer.mars/TheEarth.py">
    <!-- Else, try the MPEG video -->
    <OBJECT data="TheEarth.mpeg" type="application/mpeg">
        <!-- Else, try the GIF image -->
        <OBJECT data="TheEarth.gif" type="image/gif">
            <!-- Else render the text -->
            The <STRONG>Earth</STRONG> as seen from space.
        </OBJECT>
    </OBJECT>
</OBJECT>
```

Only ever attempting to load an image via an object is basically removing the semantic meaning off of the image, which I would consider very bad practice.

Comment: i''ve seen the same thing when using object to embed pdf with the img fallback

Answer (score 5):

There is no good *practical* reason to use `object` instead of `img`. `object` has always been inconsistently and messily supported. Use `img` for images, `embed` for flash content, and `video` or `audio` for multimedia content. Basically the only use of `object` left is for invoking specific plugins.

That said, the philosophical position for `object`'s existence is still very good. It was meant to be a generic element for any type of content which can contain nested fallback content. W3C/XHTML2 had a very idealistic roadmap for html which emphasized syntactic and semantic purity and wanted to do things like allow `href` on any element (eliminating `a`), and eliminate `img` in favor of `object`. However, browsers could never seem to get `object` right in a fully generic way. Additionally, it was difficult to define the js APIs for a generic `object` element. That's a big reason why `video` and `audio` are separate--`object` serving a video won't expose the js video APIs.

However, XHTML2 lost and HTML5 won and HTML5 favors `img`, so use `img`.

Comment: I assume you meant XHTML2 lost?  Also, isn't XHTML2's philosophy of favoring a generic `<object>` element in direct opposition of semantic purity?  `<object>` means nothing; `<img>` means it's an image.

Comment: Typo--xhtml2 lost. `object` types were supposed to be discerned by the `type` attribute. Semantically they were trying to unify the various inconsistent methods of embedding content. So `object` subsumes `iframe`, `embed`, `applet`, `img`, etc. They did not see mime type as semantically significant. This is consistent with html's resource-representation distinction, where the same url could potentially respond with an image or a video (in any number of different formats) depending on content-type negotiation. I think this way of thinking ended up being way too pure to be practical.

Comment: XHTML2 didn't eliminate `img` in favour of `object`. The `img` element was in XHTML2 right until the end. But XHTML2 allowed the `src` attribute on any element, which would make it act like an `img` element, so the `img` element was largely unnecessary in XHTML2.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a real-world use case for using object over img tags. I’m using PlantUML to generate SVGs that include tooltips. If I use the img tag to include the img, none of the native SVG pointer events events work. But if I use the object tag, presto - all over the onhover/mouseover behaviors work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced a problem which forced me to use `<object>` instead of `<img>`.

I have a file named `lv2x.php`, and I used it as a svg file (php headers `"Content-Type: image/svg+xml"`).
Inside the svg file, I imported a google font CSS link (used `link-href` or `@import`).

The problem is that: when I open the file in a new tab: `https://.../lv2x.php?lv=10` it displays the font I used for a text correctly. But when i use `<img src="https://.../lv2x.php?lv=10">`, it falls back to default font.

No matter how much I tried to find a solution, searching on Google, asking ChatGPT,... the font of the svg file keeps being wrong. The solution I found is that using `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://.../lv2x.php?lv=10">`. The font displays correctly again.

Comment: Actually, you can use custom fonts in `<img>` tags, but you need to include a `@font-face` rule with an embedded data URL for the fontfile src. Since SVGs in `<img>` tags need to be self-contained.  See also ["Cross-browser embedded font in svg image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905026/cross-browser-embedded-font-in-svg-image)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As mentioned in the article you linked here. It seems to be working when we need to encode the whole font as base64 inside the svg file, which seems not to be good for my case.
The `lv` parameter displays a number in the image, which means everytime I use another value for `lv`, it will cache the whole file including the font embedded as base64 inside them. I think it's not a good choice to cache the font data for 100 times instead of once.