# Download svg including it's text tag value

Tags: svg

I'm working on a way to download svg from a webpage.
I have pretty much everything working apart from the last part:

> Downloading the svg including the text tag included in it.

Now, to give a better background:
I will need to download images out of an svg using `fontawesome` icon as text.
The svg is properly downloaded, hower the text tag is not (it's downloaded as a broken image "square")

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
function triggerDownload(imgURI, name, format) {
    let evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: false,
        cancelable: true
    });

    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('download', name + '.' + format);
    a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

function clickSVG(event) {
    const dd = 300;
    const format = "png"
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        target = event.currentTarget;
    canvas.width = dd;
    canvas.height = dd;
    debugger
    let newImage = target.cloneNode(true),
        circle = newImage.getElementsByClassName('svgCircle-test') ? newImage.getElementsByClassName('svgCircle-test') : null,
        image = newImage.getElementsByClassName('svgImage-test');
    newImage.height.baseVal.value = dd;
    newImage.width.baseVal.value = dd;
    if (circle.length > 0) {
        circle[0].cx.baseVal.value = dd / 2;
        circle[0].cy.baseVal.value = dd / 2;
        circle[0].r.baseVal.value = dd / 2;
    }

    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(newImage),
        DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window,
        name = newImage.getAttribute('data-name'),
        img = new Image(),
        svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'}),
        url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        let imgURI = canvas
            .toDataURL(`image/${format}`)
            .replace(`image/${format}`, 'image/octet-stream');

        triggerDownload(imgURI, name, format);
    };

    img.src = url;
}

document.getElementById("svg").addEventListener("click", clickSVG)
```

The html looks like this:

```
<svg id="svg" height="200" width="200" data-name="test">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="#faa" class="svgCircle-test" />
  <text x="0" y="120" width="200" height="200" class="svgImage-test">&#xf2c6;</text>  
</svg>

<canvas id="canvas" />
```

And here's the CSS:

```
svg {
    margin-top:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

svg text{
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 100px;
}

#canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

A codepen to help you understand the issue and help me out a bit better can be found here: https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/QMmJvd

To see the issue, click on the circle (this will download the svg as a png image).

NB: If the download doesn't start, it's probably your browser blocking popups. Just allow it to see the downloaded image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

Once you "convert" the SVG file to an HTMLImageElement (`<image>`), as you are doing here onto the canvas, things change:

1. the styling you have applied to the `<text>` no longer applies.  That's because it is in the HTML file, not the SVG "file".  You need to add the styling it to the SVG itself.
2. SVGs rendered as an `<image>` need to be self contained.  They can't reference external files such as the Font Awesome font.

   To make it self contained, you need to embed the font file in the SVG itself using a Data URL.

   You'll need to add a `<style>` element to the SVG, and include a `@font-face` rule that specifies a Base64 encoded font file (or files).

[See this question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905026/cross-browser-embedded-font-in-svg-image)

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go